# How do i convert python dictionary to pandas framework

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I Have a JSON type dictionary in Python like this:

```
d = {'2022-12-21 20:00:00': {'1. open': '135.5900',
                             '2. high': '135.7300',
                             '3. low': '135.5900',
                             '4. close': '135.6700',
                             '5. volume': '18031'},
     '2022-12-21 19:45:00': {'1. open': '135.5700',
                             '2. high': '135.6000',
                             '3. low': '135.5500',
                             '4. close': '135.5700',
                             '5. volume': '4253'}}
```

and I would like to convert in into a pandas dataframe like:

```
  |timestamp           |open |high |low  |close|volume 
1 |2022-12-21 20:00:00 | 135 |135  | 135 | 135 |18031
2 |2022-12-21 19:45:00 | 134 | 112 | 123 | 231 |24124
```

I tried to do it with:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index')
```

but after this the dates become the indexing column and I want an indexing column as well:

[image]

Comment: Try this: `df.reset_index().rename(columns={'index': 'timestamp'})`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dates become the index by default. You can reset the index and rename the dates column using the [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) method:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'2022-12-21 20:00:00': {'1. open': '135.5900',
                             '2. high': '135.7300',
                             '3. low': '135.5900',
                             '4. close': '135.6700',
                             '5. volume': '18031'},
     '2022-12-21 19:45:00': {'1. open': '135.5700',
                             '2. high': '135.6000',
                             '3. low': '135.5500',
                             '4. close': '135.5700',
                             '5. volume': '4253'}}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index').reset_index(names="timestamp")
print(df)
```

The `names` argument renames the column that used to be the index (new in version *1.5.0*).

For older versions, use [`rename`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index').reset_index().rename(columns={'index': 'timestamp'})
```

Gives:

```
             timestamp   1. open   2. high    3. low  4. close 5. volume
0  2022-12-21 20:00:00  135.5900  135.7300  135.5900  135.6700     18031
1  2022-12-21 19:45:00  135.5700  135.6000  135.5500  135.5700      4253
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new column `df['new_index']=range(1, len(df) + 1)` and then set that as the new index of the dataframe `df.set_index('new_index')`.  That should definitely work.

I would also be interested to find out what happens if you try `df.reset_index()`.

You may need to set the name of the index to "timestamp" first `df.index.name="timestamp"`.

Comment: i tried df.reset_index() too it doesnt change anything after that. any other way to index it rather than adding rows because some rows are going to get deleted after some operations

Answer (score 0):

reset the index

```
self.stocks[s]= pd.DataFrame.from_dict(self.stocks[s],orient ='index').reset_index()
```